# Controller response after select one value of select option

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**Context**

I have two tables:

`Firm`table : ID (string), Firm(string)

`Firms` table:
FirmID(string FK), Name(string)

That I want to do is to select one value of `Firm` table and get it to my controller `Firm` to finally do a query depending of Firms value received

**View**

```
  <select ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="Banks= Firm[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Namefor item in Firms">
  </select><br/>
```

**JS**

```
 function GetFirm() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Firms/", null,
                function (res) {
                    $scope.Firm= res.data;
                    $scope.selected = $scope.Firms[0];
                }, errorFirm);
        }
```

**Controller I want to get value selected**

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetFirm(HttpRequestMessage request, string firm)
        {
                //some code here
        }
```

So how can I received selected value into `string firm`? , I think is another function of JS but I´m really lost there

> Note: Method whehre I want to received `string firm` is into
>   `apiService.get(../../api/Firm/"`

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: What is exactly not clear? you can ask what is not clear and I explain you more detailed @Sajeetharan

Comment: you just want to pass the selected value to the service?

Comment: Exaclty, I want to get selected value every time I clic on them and send to service or controller in my case @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the ng-change and pass the selected value,

So inside your controller,

```
$scope.filtro = function(selected){
    apiService.get(../../api/Estatus/+selected.Nombre ;
}
```